# C++ pointer arguments to a function, How can I avoid changing the inputs

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, arguments

So I have a function that takes pointers as arguments. Similar to

```
Type *Foo(unsigned int head, Type *fixed, Type *period)
{
Type *periodCopy = new Type;
*periodCopy = *period;
Type *fixedCopy = new Type;
*fixedCopy = *fixed;
...
```

I operate on periodCopy and fixedCopy in hopes of not changing fixed or period. However this doesn't seem to be the case. It still looks like I'm modifying whatever I give to the function. I'm new to c++ and pointers and I can't really wrap my head around whats happening here. Shouldn't the copies be pointing to data separate from the noncopies? This is an assignment. I'm sure I could easily get what I want if I could change the arguments from pointers, but that is not an option. Any help is appreciated. I hope this was clear enough

Comment: You're correctly making copies. Maybe the objects contain other pointers within them -- you're not copying the things they point to.

Comment: Show the definition of `Type`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn the difference between shallow and deep copies. Maybe that's even the point of the assignment.

Comment: That code is a memory leak. You need a `delete` for each `new`.

Comment: Thats a great point. The Type has a pointer within it. That passed my mind completely. Thank you

Comment: @MeMoses design your classes so that they have value semantics: a copy of one should behave how you expect a copy to expect.  An easy way to do this is to follow the Rule of Zero: make your class only contain data members that themselves have value semantics (e.g. dont use any raw pointers to resources which your class owns).

Comment: It sounds like `Type`  is broken in some sense, probably violating the [rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are making copy of yourself. So, you need to make sure that you delete the copy of period and fixed before returning from the function.

If copy is not required, then use const pointer in the function.

```
Type *Foo(unsigned int head, const Type *fixed, const Type *period)
```

A better way is to use reference.

```
Type *Foo(unsigned int head, const Type &fixed, const Type &period)
 //Now treat fixed and period as a normal object.
```

In case, you do need copy, pass the argument by value. That will automatically take care of creating and destroying the object. But copy constructor must be public.

```
 Type *Foo(unsigned int head, Type fixed, Type period)
```

Comment: This answer is wrong; `*periodCopy = *period;` is correct and makes a copy of the value pointed to by the argument (using the assignment operator)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: OK; however he's indicated he wants to work on copies of the values being pointed to (or being referred to) so we have to address the issue of how to make a copy. He  does have to either keep the same code he already has, or use the copy-constructor which should achieve the same result.   Either way, his real problem is that his assignment operator is not implemented properly.